# PickerView for date and time

Tags: iphone

I have used uipickerview from interface in my application.But it is not selecting the current date and time.Please,help me.

Thanks

Comment: Did you use just UIPickerView or UIDatePicker? Did you try to set date & time from code or with user interactions?

Answer (score 0):

provide some code i think this will help...

do you have selected the property MaxDate as today ? if not then select as.